# RedisServerException: ERR Error running script

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

I'm connecting to the redis server. then saying redis-server. i'm getting the client up with redis-cli. I have my own MVC project. and the Products controller looks like this

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

        public ProductsController(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
        {
            _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            DistributedCacheEntryOptions cacheEntryOptions = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions();

            cacheEntryOptions.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

            _distributedCache.SetString("name","Berkay",cacheEntryOptions);


            return View();
        }
    }
```

WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
the error points here.

**`_distributedCache.SetString("name","Berkay",cacheEntryOptions);`**

also, my startup file looks like this. I have also made my definitions in ConfigureService

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(opt =>
            {
                opt.Configuration = "localhost:6379";
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the library you're using here is using a script that assumes the key given is a "hash" type, in particular: a hash created solely through the same library and script (using different sub-values for the stored value, rolling expiration details, etc). But it seems that your key isn't - perhaps it is a raw "string" type. You could use various redis tools ("debug object", for example) to investigate the key, but it is probably easier to just nuke it from orbit, if this is a cache server, and assume a blank slate used only by your current library choices.